# Java AWT GUI container to hold a top and a bottom half?

Tags: java

I have two panels that I want to organize onto another panel.

I need a container that will allow me to split them in half. So each panel takes up half the containing panel (separated top/bottom style), like in the image below:

```
-------
|     |
|     |
-------
|     |
|     |
-------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not BoxLayout, **GridLayout** will allow you to use two equal halves, i.e., `new GridLayout(2, 1)` for two rows, one column  -- but more importantly you're far better off reading the tutorials and [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) before asking this here as it's all explained in detail: [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: *"`new GridLayout(2, 1)` for two rows, one column"* `new GridLayout(0, 1)` with two components will achieve the same thing, and there are less source edits if you want to add a 3rd component.  Yes I know *"It'll never happen!"*. ;)