# GridBagLayout is not working

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

```
this.rootComponent.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();

        //gbc.gridwidth=2;
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridwidth=8;
        gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

        this.rootComponent.add(new JLabel("Test label 1"),gbc);

        gbc.gridx=8;
        gbc.gridy=12;
        gbc.gridwidth=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

        this.rootComponent.add(new JLabel("Test label"),gbc);
```

Want to format it like this. grey part shows the jpanel part. Initially i want to layout the first 2 jpanel correctly . which is not working. how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: this could be job exactly for MigLayout, [but no issue for GBC, you can to set percentual Dimension for GBC too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9015259/714968)

Comment: What on Earth possessed you post an image with dimensions 3,828px × 1,872px?  See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: @fallenAngel : I hope the edited answer, will help you understand the `GridBagLayout` a  bit more better, please have a look at that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are failing to specify any `weightx` and `weighty` values to the `GridBagConstraints`. Moreover your `gridwidth` values are wrong, since it only needs to be `2` for the bottom most `JPanel`, for the rest it needs to be `1`.

---

**Explanation of what I am doing :** 
Consider `JPanel`s `BLUE` and `RED`, they are to be placed along the **X-AXIS**, in the ratio
`70:30`, with respect to each other (therefore their `weightx` will be `0.7` and `0.3` respectively. Since the total area along the **X-AXIS** is `1.0`).

Now both of these `BLUE` and `RED JPanel`s are to be placed along the **Y-AXIS**, with respect to the third `GREEN JPanel` in the ratio `90:10`, therefore, both of these `BLUE` and `RED` will have `weighty = 0.9`, and the `GREEN JPanel` will have `weighty = 0.1`, but since `GREEN JPanel` is suppose to occupy the whole area (with respect to **X-AXIS**), as occupied by `BLUE` and `RED JPanel`s, for that matter, its `gridwidth = 2` and `weightx = 1.0`.

---

Try this code example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagLayoutExample
{
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public GridBagLayoutExample()
    {
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = getPanel(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel leftPanel = getPanel(Color.BLUE);
        JPanel rightPanel = getPanel(Color.RED);
        JPanel bottomPanel = getPanel(Color.GREEN.darker());

        addComp(contentPane, leftPanel
                , 0, 0, 0.7, 0.9, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        addComp(contentPane, rightPanel
                , 1, 0, 0.3, 0.9, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        addComp(contentPane, bottomPanel
                , 0, 1, 1.0, 0.1, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp
                            , int gridX, int gridY
                            , double weightX, double weightY
                            , int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int fill)
    {
        gbc.gridx = gridX;
        gbc.gridy = gridY;
        gbc.weightx = weightX;
        gbc.weighty = weightY;
        gbc.gridwidth = gridWidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridHeight;
        gbc.fill = fill;

        panel.add(comp, gbc);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel(Color backColour)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(backColour);
        panel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBagLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Here is the OUTPUT of the same :

[image: GridBagLayoutExample]