# How do I fill the whole Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am fairly new to GUIs in Java. What I want to know is, is there a way to take two `JPanels` and divide it up in the `JFrame`, ie. 70% for panel 1 and 30% for panel 2?

Here is a snippet from where I create my GUI:

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class ButtonGrid extends Game
{
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

private static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();

private static JLabel lblP1 = new JLabel("Player 1: ");
private static JLabel lblP2 = new JLabel("Player 2: ");
private static JLabel P1Score = new JLabel("0");
private static JLabel P2Score = new JLabel("0");

public static JButton grid[][];

public ButtonGrid(int width, int length)
{
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length));


    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length));

    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel4, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    lblP1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    lblP2.setForeground(Color.red);

    grid = new JButton[width][length];

    for(int x=0; x<length; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<width; y++)
        {
            grid[x][y] = new JButton();
            grid[x][y].addActionListener(actionListener);
            grid[x][y].setName("[" + x + ',' +y + "]");
            //grid[x][y].setText(grid[x][y].getName());
            //frame.add(grid[x][y]);
            panel1.add(grid[x][y]);
        }
    }

    grid[0][0].setBackground(Color.blue);
    grid[width-1][length-1].setBackground(Color.red);

    panel3.add(lblP1);
    panel3.add(P1Score);
    panel4.add(lblP2);
    panel4.add(P2Score);

    panel2.add(panel3);
    panel2.add(panel4);


    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.add(panel1);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

}
```

What I would like is for the buttons to be even sized and filled to the bottom, now there is about 2/3 of empty space in the frame. How do I fill the rest of the 2/3 of space in the frame with the buttons?

Comment: i think that MigLayout or mad's answer

Comment: Don't over use `static`, there's no need for any of the `static` references present in your code, as they are all `private`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), it allows you to specify the weight that should be applied to each component.

For example...

```
JPanel top = new JPanel();
top.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
bottom .setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));

JPanel parent = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weighty = 0.7;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
parent.add(top, gbc);

gbc.gridy++;
gbc.weighty = 0.3;
parent.add(bottom, gbc);
```

Side Notes:

- Don't over use `static`, there's no need for any of the `static` references present in your code, as they are all `private`...
- Don't create a frame within a `JPanel` (or any other type of container).  The component should not care about where it might be used, that's an external decision...
- Using `setResizable` will change the size of the viewable area and should be done before setting the size of the window.  You should rely on `pack` instead of `setSize` as this will size the window so that the content size is honoured

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use GridBagConstraints. It worked well. Also found this that was useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014068/how-to-use-gridbagconstraints-to-create-the-layout